# placing a widget in the background in SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, swt

I'm trying to display a progress bar (using SWT's ProgressBar class). However, the bar isn't very visible due to my window's background. Therefore, I'm trying to put a white rectangle (using GC.fillRoundedRectangle()) behind the progress bar. I can't find a way to display the progress bar on top of the rectangle. How can I achieve "layering" in SWT?

Thanks!

EDIT: I tried @greg-449's suggestion, but all I got was a blank window-am I implementing this wrong?

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Display d = new Display();
    Shell parent = new Shell(d);
    parent.setSize(500, 500);
    parent.open();
    makeBar(parent);

    while (!parent.isDisposed()) {
        if (!d.readAndDispatch()) {
            d.sleep();
        }
    }
}

private static void makeBar(Shell parent) {
    Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    layout.marginHeight = 20;
    layout.marginWidth = 20;
    body.setLayout(layout);

    body.addListener(SWT.Paint, event ->
      {
        Rectangle rect = body.getClientArea();
        event.gc.setBackground(body.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
        event.gc.fillRoundRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, 20, 20);
      });

    ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(body, SWT.HORIZONTAL);

    bar.setMaximum(100);
    bar.setSelection(40);       
}
```

This is what I see when I run this code:

[Output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfmJ8.png)

Comment: You haven't set a layout on your Shell, every Composite (including Shell) must have a layout. I used `shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());`

Comment: @greg-449 the issue with layouts is that adding a layout to my shell messes up the other buttons and text fields I have on my shell-is there any way to do this without adding a layout to my shell?

Comment: You can mess around with setBounds but I can't help you with that as I never use.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a `Composite` which you paint with the `ProgressBar` as a child.

Something like:

```
Composite body = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
layout.marginHeight = 20;
layout.marginWidth = 20;
body.setLayout(layout);

body.addListener(SWT.Paint, event ->
  {
    Rectangle rect = body.getClientArea();
    event.gc.setBackground(body.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_WHITE));
    event.gc.fillRoundRectangle(rect.x, rect.y, rect.width, rect.height, 20, 20);
  });

ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar(body, SWT.HORIZONTAL);

bar.setMaximum(100);
bar.setSelection(40);
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried this, but it didn't work. See the question for code and output.